# showing array by group on php is not working as expected

Tags: php, arrays

I want to be very straight forward.

It the HTML form I have created with the touch of JavaScript. It has an option to increase/delete the table (i didn't attached the code here- just wanted to make sure you know about this in case. ). I here in this example i am using 3 rows.

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="case" type="checkbox"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" data-type="productCode" name="itemNo[]" id="itemNo_1" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter IMEI number"></td>
    <td><input type="text" data-type="productName" name="itemName[]" id="itemName_1" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Brand"></td>
    <td><input type="text" data-type="productName" name="brand[]" id="itemName_2" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Model"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="price[]" id="price_1" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>
    <td><input type="number" value="1" name="quantity[]" id="quantity_1" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" disabled></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="total[]" id="total_1" class="form-control totalLinePrice" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" disabled></td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
```

Once I process it through php POST method, the data really pass. I called them in specific loop like following.

```
$itemNo = $_POST['itemNo'];
$itemName = $_POST['itemName'];
$brand = $_POST['brand'];
$price = $_POST['price'];

foreach($itemNo as $itemNo) {
    echo $itemNo.'<br/>';
}

foreach( $itemName as $itemName ) {
print $itemName.'<br/>';
}

foreach( $brand as $brand ) {
print $brand.'<br/>';
}

foreach( $price as $price ) {
print $price.'<br/>';
}
```

Its gives me output like following:

```
field 1 data of 1st row
field 1 data of 2nd row
field 1 data of 3rd row

field 2 data of 1st row
field 2 data of 2nd row
field 2 data of 3rd row

field 3 data of 1st row
field 3 data of 2nd row
field 3 data of 3rd row

field 4 data of 1st row
field 4 data of 2nd row
field 4 data of 3rd row
```

I actually am struggling to get the output like this--

```
field 1 data of 1st row
field 2 data of 1st row
field 3 data of 1st row
field 4 data of 1st row

field 1 data of 2nd row
field 2 data of 2nd row
field 3 data of 2nd row
field 4 data of 2nd row

field 1 data of 3rd row
field 2 data of 3rd row
field 3 data of 3rd row
field 4 data of 3rd row
```

So hopefully i can use single loop to get this required output.

Any idea or help should be appreciated.

Thanks
Fiona

Comment: can you show us the array $_POST['itemNo'] how you are getting it from browser. I think for loop can solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilize the `$key` part of the `foreach($array as $key => $value)` to get your desired results. see http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

```
$itemNos = $_POST['itemNo'];
$itemNames = $_POST['itemName'];
$brands = $_POST['brand'];
$prices = $_POST['price'];

foreach($itemNos as $key => $value) {
    echo '<p>';
    echo $itemNos[$key].'<br/>';
    echo $itemNames[$key].'<br/>';
    echo $brands[$key].'<br/>';
    echo $prices[$key];
    echo '</p>';
}
```